# Remove footer from embedded Power BI report

Tags: html, iframe, layout, powerbi

I embedded Power BI into my web page using iframe code but I would like to hide the footer with share buttons. Is there any way to achieve this?
I'm specifically talking about embed code (iframe), not public URL.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is very hard to answer, _1) there is no sample code posted.  2) you dont list which approach you used. 3) you havent listed what options your tried 4) you did not list where it failed for you_. I have given you 3 options below, and I personally use some of them and they work.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, PowerBI returns the Iframe with it to show it was created by PowerBI, with the name embedded.

Depending on how you created it you have some *options*.

1. JavaScript with CSS to hide the footer.
2. If you used the UI, from the UI using this
   [link](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/269051/hiding-header-and-footer-from-power-bi-dashboard-on-d365-dashboard/816626), as *described below from the site in link* [image]
3. Some code to help you out: at configuration you can setup various values, and set your
   footer to false

---

```
 <html>

  <script src="https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/bower_components/powerbi-client/dist/powerbi.js""></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var embedConfiguration = {
          type: 'report',
          accessToken: 'someToken',
          id: '71.Tykt.org',
          embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=xxx.TYKT.org',
        settings: {
                      filterPaneEnabled: false,
                      navContentPaneEnabled: false
                      // Find the setting you want to hide and set it to False
                    } 
      }; 

      var report;

      window.onload = function () {  
      var $reportContainer = $('#reportContainer'); 
       report= powerbi.embed($reportContainer.get(0), embedConfiguration);

      }  

   </script>

   <div id="reportContainer"></div>
 </html>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please can you explain the java script code. What is supposed to be here:  
** accessToken: 'someToken'**,
** id: '71.Tykt.org**'
When I publish to web i get public url:
** https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNjJmZGM1ZWQtMDZhZi00M.........CI6IjFmZjk5YTkyLTdlOTgtNDhkMS04ZjM4LTUzNjFkM2QzMWZlNiIsImMiOjl9** 
and embed code 
**<iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNjJmZGM1ZWQtMDZhZi00M.........CI6IjFmZjk5YTkyLTdlOTgtNDhkMS04ZjM4LTUzNjFkM2QzMWZlNiIsImMiOjl9" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>**

Comment: Please can you explain what is supposed to be here: **accessToken: 'someToken'** and **id: '71.Tykt.org'**?
When I publish to web i get public URL and embed code. is there anything else to be added to **settings** part of the code?

Comment: This solution isn't clear and can't accept as solution.